# Public variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to declare public variables in asp.net.  I am used to with doing this in vb.net, where I declare them in modules but do not know how to do it in asp.net
Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear. What have you tried? ASP.NET also has classes and modules. But note that everything in a module is shared, so it's the same for every request of every user.

Comment: Do not ever do this. Ever. Especially not in ASP.NET, where these "variables" would be shared across all requests and all users.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I need to take user name in one asp.net form and then display it in another.  In vb.net I do it through Public variables declared in modules.  What do u suggest in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Public variables are generally considered to be bad practise especially in ASP.NET applications ([Global variable (or alternative) best practise in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507864/global-variable-or-alternative-best-practise-in-net))

Here are three options for sharing data between asp.net pages:

1. Cookies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX
2. Session State variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx
3. Query String: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

All have their pros and cons so I would suggest a bit of background reading before deciding on which one suits your application

If you *really* want to use a public variable in your ASP.NET application you can do this, just create a module and declare a variable in it like you would with WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx) variables for your scenario.

I would suggest first reading up and understanding how session state works in ASP.net, MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Sessions exist per user, an example of using it within ASP.net is:

```
Session("FirstName") = FirstNameTextBox.Text
```

You can then access the session variables on other pages accessed by the same session id (user).

Comment: `Session("FirstName") = FirstNameTextBox.Text` for the VB version